# Httget request using HttpClient 4.5

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I'm trying to update a code that uses HttpClient 4.5 to have no deprecated methods, but it was completely impossible to find a solution, I'm totally lost.

This is my code:

```
public int sendGetHTTP() throws QAException, IOException {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("my");

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("cert", caCert);

        tmf.init(ks);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        Scheme scheme = new Scheme("https", sf, 444);
        client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(scheme);
        client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://mysite:444/en.html");
        httpGet.addHeader("SSO-EMPLOYEENUMBER", "1234");
        httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status != HTTP_STATUS_OK && status != HTTP_STATUS_CREATED) {
        throw new QAException("Server Response: " + status + ": " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    }
    return status;
}
```

How can I change this code to not have deprecated methods and instances (like the `DefaultHttpClient`) ?

Is there any useful documentation that I can read ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache maintains a [deprecated list](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/deprecated-list.html)

You can check on that list to see what they recommend you replace it with, and the version of the client it was deprecated in.

For DefaultHttpClient, they recommend

> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient (4.3) use
>   HttpClientBuilder see also CloseableHttpClient.

You can also go to the [HttpComponents Home Page](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) which has links to examples and doc's